# pandas assigning series view to a series view doesn't work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, series

I'm trying to take a slice view from a series (logically indexed by a conditional), process it then assign the result back to that logically-indexed slice.
The LHS and RHS in the assign are Series with matching indices, but the assign ends up being scalar for some unknown reason (see bottom). How to get the desired assign? (I checked SO and [pandas 0.11.0 doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) for anything related).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# A dataframe with sample data and some boolean conditional
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': range(1,20)})
df['cond'] = df.x.apply(lambda xx: ((xx%3)==1) )

# Create a new col and selectively assign to it... elsewhere being NaN...
df['newcol'] = np.nan
# This attempted assign to a view of the df doesn't work (in reality the RHS expression would actually be a return value from somefunc)
df.ix[df.cond, df.columns.get_loc('newcol')] = 2* df.ix[df.cond, df.columns.get_loc('x')]
# yet a scalar assign does...
df.ix[df.cond, df.columns.get_loc('newcol')] = 99.
# Likewise bad trying to use -df.cond as the logical index:
df.ix[-df.cond, df.columns.get_loc('newcol')] = 2* df.ix[-df.cond, df.columns.get_loc('x')]
```

Currently I just get a stupid scalar assign:

```
>>> df.ix[-df.cond, df.columns.get_loc('newcol')] = 2* df.ix[-df.cond, df.columns.get_loc('x')]
>>> df
     x   cond  newcol
0    1   True     NaN
1    2  False       4
2    3  False       4
3    4   True     NaN
4    5  False       4
5    6  False       4
6    7   True     NaN
7    8  False       4
8    9  False       4
9   10   True     NaN
10  11  False       4
11  12  False       4
12  13   True     NaN
13  14  False       4
14  15  False       4
15  16   True     NaN
16  17  False       4
17  18  False       4
18  19   True     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': range(1,20)})

In [22]: df['cond'] = df.x.apply(lambda xx: ((xx%3)==1) )

In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
     x   cond
0    1   True
1    2  False
2    3  False
3    4   True
4    5  False
5    6  False
6    7   True
7    8  False
8    9  False
9   10   True
10  11  False
11  12  False
12  13   True
13  14  False
14  15  False
15  16   True
16  17  False
17  18  False
18  19   True

In [24]: df['newcol'] = 2*df.loc[df.cond, 'x']

In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
     x   cond  newcol
0    1   True       2
1    2  False     NaN
2    3  False     NaN
3    4   True       8
4    5  False     NaN
5    6  False     NaN
6    7   True      14
7    8  False     NaN
8    9  False     NaN
9   10   True      20
10  11  False     NaN
11  12  False     NaN
12  13   True      26
13  14  False     NaN
14  15  False     NaN
15  16   True      32
16  17  False     NaN
17  18  False     NaN
18  19   True      38


In [10]: def myfunc(df_):
   ....:     return 2 * df_
   ....: 

 In [26]: df['newcol'] = myfunc(df.ix[df.cond, df.columns.get_loc('newcol')])

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
     x   cond  newcol
0    1   True       4
1    2  False     NaN
2    3  False     NaN
3    4   True      16
4    5  False     NaN
5    6  False     NaN
6    7   True      28
7    8  False     NaN
8    9  False     NaN
9   10   True      40
10  11  False     NaN
11  12  False     NaN
12  13   True      52
13  14  False     NaN
14  15  False     NaN
15  16   True      64
16  17  False     NaN
17  18  False     NaN
18  19   True      76
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround:

```
tmp = pd.Series(np.repeat(np.nan, len(df)))
tmp[-cond] = 2* df.loc[df.cond, 'x']
df['newcol'] = tmp
```

Strangely, the following sometimes works (assigning the slice to the entire Series)
(but fails with a more complex RHS with `AssertionError: Length of values does not match length of index`)

(According to pandas doc, the RHS Series indexes are supposed to get aligned to the LHS, well at least if the LHS is a dataframe - but not if it's a Series? Is this a bug?)

```
>>> df['newcol'] = 2* df.loc[df.cond, 'x']
>>> df
     x   cond  newcol
0    1   True       2
1    2  False     NaN
2    3  False     NaN
3    4   True       8
4    5  False     NaN
5    6  False     NaN
6    7   True      14
7    8  False     NaN
8    9  False     NaN
9   10   True      20
10  11  False     NaN
11  12  False     NaN
12  13   True      26
13  14  False     NaN
14  15  False     NaN
15  16   True      32
16  17  False     NaN
17  18  False     NaN
18  19   True      38
```

[Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644898/jeff), what's weird is we can assign to df['newcol'] (which is supposed to be a copy not a view, right?)
when we do:

```
df['newcol'] = 2* df.loc[df.cond, 'x']
```

but not when we do the same with the RHS coming from a fn:

```
def myfunc(df_):
    """Some func transforming and returning said Series slice"""
    return 2* df_

df['newcol'] = myfunc( df.ix[df.cond, df.columns.get_loc('newcol')] )
```

Comment: this is correct; what are you using in the rhs that gets the assertion error? it must be align able or equal length to the index in the case of a list/numpy array

Comment: Jeff - see addendum at bottom

Comment: This all works; can you show the actual output of what you are getting? ``df['newcol']`` is a Series whos data *in this case* is a view (as its float data), so modifications WILL affect the frame - this is not always the case, however, e.g. say you have a int dtype then you assign a ``np.nan`` to it, then you would be modifiying a copy which is then assigned back to the frame

Comment: FYI, ``df.columns.get_loc('newcol')`` is not needed, just use 'newcol'